# calculation of vector product $\ddot{\gamma} (t) \times \dot{\gamma} (t)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

$$\ddot{\gamma} (t) \times \dot{\gamma} (t)=(-a\cos t, -a\sin t, 0)\times (-a\sin t, a\cos t, b)$$
The writer will get the following result $$(-ab\sin t, ab\cos t, -a^2)$$

but I don't know how to compute the product. Please teach me this step by step  clearly and explanatorily. Thank you for help.

Comment: Hi Nil--sorry I haven't answered your email yet; I will soon.  Meanwhile, do you know how to calulate $a \times b$ for $a, b \in \Bbb R^3$?  Do you know that $a \times a = 0$ for any such $a$?

Comment: where did that b come from? is there a typo?

Comment: You must have something wrong above. The cross product of a vector with itself is always zero.

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong. i editted it. @achillehui

Comment: no i am always confused while computing such product. no problem. see you soon:) @RobertLewis

Comment: Look at the section "Computing the cross product" part of the wiki page of [Cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Computing_the_cross_product). It has all the steps you need to calculate the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
  & (-a \cos t, -a \sin t, 0) \times (-a \sin t, a \cos t, b)\\
\\
= & \begin{vmatrix}
\hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z}\\
-a \cos t & -a \sin t & 0 \\
-a \sin t & a \cos t & b
\end{vmatrix}\\
\\
= & \hat{x}( b(-a \sin t)-0)-\hat{y} (-ab\cos t-0) +\hat{z}(-a^2 \cos^{2}t-a^2 \sin^{2}t)\\
= & \hat{x}(-ab\sin t)+\hat{y}(ab\cos t)+\hat{z}(-a^2(\cos^{2}t+\sin^{2}t))\\
= & (-ab\sin t,ab\cos t,-a^2)
\end{align}$$
since $\sin^{2}t+\cos^{2}t=1$.